# Moving error conditionals out of the view. -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have a form that has a text field for name, it has a presence validation on it. When a user forgets to input the name the text field turns red this is all fine but I'd like to clean up my view a little bit but I'm not sure how? Maybe a helper? Maybe a method? I'm a bit new to rails and I'm looking for some advice on this problem. Here is my code for the view.

VIEW

```
    <% if f.object.errors[:name].present? %>
     <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'alert' %>
     <div class="validation">
      <% f.object.errors[:name].each do |error| %>
        <%= error %>
       <% end %>
     </div>
      <% else %>
       <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <% end %>
```

It's a pretty standard if else statment but I'd think its a little too ugly for the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a similar result using your model validation. If you require a presence validation on a model, then it will tell the user the field cannot be blank. This would allow you to tell the user they cannot leave a form field blank without manually coding this in your views.

Example: Post Model - app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :body, :presence => true
end
```

If the user now attempts to submit the form with either Title or Body empty then they will be asked to resubmit the form, with a little tool tip saying "Please fill out this field".

No logic is needed in the view to achieve this, simply validate presence in your model.

Comment: Link to tool tip screenshot - ![validation error](http://i.imgur.com/A9PyYuD.png)